# Kronecker Delta as a Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra, kronecker-delta

Let $\delta^i_j$ be the Kronecker delta function, i.e. $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then, it is easy to verify that this value is a rank 2 mixed tensor of one covariant index and one contravariant index. But, what does this mean intuitively? How does it make sense to interpret $\delta^i_j$ under a change of basis? The function is the identity matrix which is invariant under any change of basis.

Comment: What is special about this function though? Aren't all 2x2 matrices rank 2 mixed tensors? Also, I am trying to understand how the Kronecker delta changes under a change of basis. It just gives you a 1 if the two indices equal each other... this does not seem to be related to any basis.

Comment: Well, why is this the identity function since $\delta$ is a function of 2 variables? The matrices coincide though.